# Scaling replication controllers via API in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to scale replication controller via API in kubernetes.

By using kubeclt command, it may be done by running:

```
kubectl scale --replicas=1 --namespace=kube-system rc my_replication_controller
```

But how to achieve it using API?

Moving through docs, I found only "replace scale of the specified Scale" and "partially update scale of the specified Scale" among write operations. But I think this is not what I need.

Comment: In general, you can use the `--v=9` flag of `kubectl` to see which API call it uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long playing with it and consulting on slack DevOps chat, I was able to figure it out. Here is a workable curl:

```
curl -sSk -H \"Authorization: Bearer ${KUBE_TOKEN}\" -H 'Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json' -X 'PATCH' $URL_NAME/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/replicationcontrollers/kube-registry-v0 -d '{"spec": {"replicas":  1}}'
```

One of the important components here is "`Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json`" Without it specification, Kubernetes will not recognize data in API request correctly.